# Why UIWebView in UICollectionView does not scroll?

Tags: scroll, uiwebview

I have a `UICollectionView` and one of the cells has a `UIWebView`. I have set up everything but the `UIWebView`still does not `scroll` and the `website` loaded does not respond when clicking. Please help to find out possible reasons. I have added the following code to the `UIWebView`:

```
        cell.redemWebview.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        cell.redemWebview.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
        [cell.redemWebview.scrollView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:YES];
        cell.redemWebview.scalesPageToFit = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding this line in the cell. I hope this can help someone.

```
[self bringSubviewToFront:self.redemWebview];
```